# Connecting Codeigniter 3 with MS SQL Server using odbc

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a CI project that needs to connect to remote SQL Server 2000 database and I am using ODBC driver. I keep getting Database Error :

**A PHP Error was encountered**

> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: odbc_pconnect(): SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager]
>   Data source name not found and no default driver specified, SQL state
>   IM002 in SQLConnect
>
> Filename: odbc/odbc_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 140
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: C:\wamp\www\xxx\application\controllers\Welcome.php Line: 30
>   Function: __construct
>
> File: C:\wamp\www\xxx\index.php Line: 315 Function: require_once

here is my **database configuration** :

```
$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => 'MyServerName',
    'hostname' => 'Driver={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};Server=ServerIPAddress;Database=MyDB;',
    'username' => 'sa',
    'password' => 'sa',
    'database' => '*MyDB*',
    'dbdriver' => 'odbc',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => TRUE,
    'db_debug' => TRUE,
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

Comment: Why are you using ODBC and not the native driver?

Comment: ODBC is needed to connect to sql server 2000 version right? although i'm not sure what you mean, what are you suggesting sir?

Comment: Hi Dale, did you ever get this to work? If so can you share, I'm having the same issue and have sent hours trying to find a solution. Thank you in advance.

Comment: hi @user752746 I solved it see my answer, man i'm sorry just got my SO account back lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi I know this is soooo late as I just recovered my account details here in SO, so I solved this problem by using this as a hostname in the database.php file

```
'hostname' => 'Driver={SQL Server};Server=<*Server IP Address*>;Database=<*Database Name>*;',
```